# List Item Sort Order - TFS Work Items

Tags: tfs

Is there any way to display the vaule order as the same given below in the work item template. 
When I see the template the value display order is changed. It is sorted alphabetically. Is there any way to change the sort order ?

```
    <ALLOWEDVALUES>
        <LISTITEM value="Pass" />
        <LISTITEM value="Fail" />
        <LISTITEM value="Blocked" />
        <LISTITEM value="N/A" />
        <LISTITEM value="Not Completed" />
        <LISTITEM value="Ready For Review" />
        <LISTITEM value="Approved" />
      </ALLOWEDVALUES>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the sort order. As a workaround you could prefix your list items as a way to achieve the order you prefer.

```
  <ALLOWEDVALUES>
    <LISTITEM value="[1] Pass" />
    <LISTITEM value="[2] Fail" />
    <LISTITEM value="[3] Blocked" />
    <LISTITEM value="[4] N/A" />
    <LISTITEM value="[5] Not Completed" />
    <LISTITEM value="[6] Ready For Review" />
    <LISTITEM value="[7] Approved" />
  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
```